# What to do if the best answer was not awarded the bounty?

Tags: support, reputation, bounties

Case in point: [Get records based on Current Date and Configured Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24609263/get-records-based-on-current-date-and-configured-data/24695249?noredirect=1#comment38296112_24695249)

Obviously, I may have a biased opinion, but I am less likely to participate and help others if I see a bounty awarded to a less useful answer.

Seemed to be the best way to build up reputation, since I can't do much of anything at this point. Rep=16.

Comment: Not sure what you expect to hear. "Ban the user who gave bounty to wrong person and force him to give to you"? If the bounty is the one and only reason you post answers, well, maybe Stack Overflow isn't the best place for you.

Comment: okay, officially frustrated.  I want to help others, but the system (reputation) is tying my hands.

Comment: Why tying your hands?? You can post answers with 1 rep as easily as user with 1000000 rep can post answer.

Comment: As you note, you have a biased opinion. Others will think other answers are 'the best'. Clearly, the person who gave the bounty did.

Comment: sorry, everyone. ramblings of a newb. issue with not being able to comment. not knowing how to get rep. please disregard my ignorance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You do nothing, and move on.

Awarding the bounty is the prerogative of the person setting the bounty, we cannot make them change their mind.

Comment: Understood. Just frustrated with the system. Trying to help people, but can't. See comment above. I'll live. (case in point, I can't even up vote your answer!)

Comment: @CamperWill you can Accept the answer. Gives more rep than upvoting. And getting 15 rep which is required to upvote is really trivial.